# ucanaccess connected to a hosted database

Tags: java, sql, database, web, ucanaccess

I am having an issue getting ucanaccess to connect to my database. While building the application I have maintained the database locally have been able to connect to it by passing the local file path in the URL. I am now trying to move this online and have tried changing the URL to a tempt online test website. I have created a temp website name and am hosting a copy of the database locally here:

http://www.ifdc.cf/prdssoffline/prdds.accdb

I have tried tweaking my URL but continue to get driver errors. Has anyone been able to connect ucanaccess to an online database? Can anyone provide an example or help correct my surely silly mistake?

Thanks as usual for your time and efforts I always learn a lot from the this sites users!

```
package contactDatabase;

import java.sql.*;


public class ContactDatabase {

private static String DRIVER = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver";
private static String URL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://http://www.ifdc.cf/prdssoffline/prdss.accdb";

private static Connection conn = null;

public ContactDatabase() {

}

public static void connect() {
    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void close() {
    try {
        getConn().close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Connection getConn() {
    return conn;
}
}
```

Edited to fix URL.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't supported, you would need a web app acting as jdbc proxy, not just exposing a file under http.